# Are there any 27" residential ovens that can accomodate a 3/4 sheet pan?

Tags: equipment, oven, shopping

I am moving into a house that needs a new oven.  We aren't going to renovate the entire kitchen; we just want to swap out the oven.  The current cabinet space for the oven can hold at most a 27 inch oven.  I know that most modern 30"+ ovens are big enough to hold a 3/4 sheet pan (which measures 21" x 15"), however, most 27" ovens I've seen are not big enough.  We are currently in the process of scouring the stores, pan-in-hand, to see if any are large enough, but I figured I'd ask here first. Are we out of luck?  Are there any 27" ovens that are wide enough to accomodate a 3/4 sheet pan?

**Edit:** Should I mark this community wiki?

**Update:** The [KitchenAid True Convection Architect 27"](http://www.kitchenaid.com/flash.cmd?/#/product/KEBS177SSS/) has interior dimensions of 22" width, 16" height, and 18.75" depth, which appears to be just big enough for a 3/4 sheet pan.

**Update #2:** It turns out my cabinet was just wide enough to actually fit a 30" oven, so this question is now pretty much moot for me.  I'm going to leave it open for a while in case anyone else was interested in the answers.

Comment: Don't go solely by the measurements -- Bring a pan to the store.

Comment: I'm still going to try them out with a pan; I just want to know if there are other brands to look at (so I can find stores that carry them).

Comment: No reason to make this community wiki; this question won't have an unlimited number of valid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The KitchenAid True Convection Architect 27" has interior dimensions of 22" width, 16" height, and 18.75" depth, which appears to be just big enough for a 3/4 sheet pan. ([per OP](http://www.kitchenaid.com/flash.cmd?/#/product/KEBS177SSS/))

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with an earlier model of the [GE Profile Advantium](http://products.geappliances.com/ApplProducts/Dispatcher?REQUEST=SpecPage&Sku=PSB1000NWW). It's actually a super awesome oven.